# c++ function parameter identifier not found

Tags: c++

I try to write program to manage Store. it has some users and goods and Order.
this is my User.h, Good.h files:

User.h:

```
#ifndef _USER
#define _USER

#include "Store.h"
#include "Good.h"

namespace question1
{
    class User
    {
        const Store store;
    public:
        User(Store &s) : store ( s )
        {
        }
    };

    class AdminUser:User
    {
    };

    class DeliveryUser:User
    {
    };

    class OrderUser:User
    {
        void registerOrder(Order &o);
    };

    class ReceptionUser:User
    {
        void importGood(Good &g);
        void increaseGood(Good &g);
    };
}

#endif
```

and Good.h:

```
#ifndef _GOOD
#define _GOOD

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "User.h"

namespace question1
{
                                                    class Date
{
 public:
    Date ();
    Date ( int mn, int day, int yr);  // constructor
    void display();                   // function to display date
    int GetMonth();
    void SetMonth(int mn);
    ~Date();
 private:
    int month, day, year;
    int DaysSoFar();
};

    enum Ordertype{Newly_registered, Check, Answered};

    class Order
    {
        int num;
        std::string customerName;
        Date registered, Check;
        Ordertype type;
        std::vector<int> codelist, numlist;
    public:
        Order();
        Order(Order& o);
    };

                        class ImportDate
{
    Date importDate;
    User importer;
    int num;
};

                            class ExportDate
{
    Date exportDate;
    User exporter;
    int num;
    Order ex;
};

    class Good
    {
        std::string name;
        int code;
        Date in;
        int innum, AvailableNum;
        User importer;
        std::vector<ImportDate> importHistory;
        std::vector<ExportDate> exportHistory;
    public:
        Good();
        Good(Good &g);
    };

                int max (int a, int b)
{
   if (a>b) return(a) ; else return (b);
}

                int min (int a, int b)
{
   if (a>b) return(b); else return (a);
}
}

#endif
```

but when compile just this two codes, i got error in User File that

> "syntax error : identifier 'Order', Line 28
>
> "syntax error : identifier 'Good', Line 33
>
> "syntax error : identifier 'Good', Line 34

in the function parameter list.
I use visual studio 2010. and open empty project.

anybody can help me?

Comment: You have a circular reference in your `#include` statements. the first header includes the other which includes the first and so on and so forth.

Comment: @Captain Oblivious i think that's what the #ifndef and #define statements are for. but i would still give that a shot

Comment: @TaylorFlores header guards prevent the contents of a header file from being compiled more than once. It does nothing to prevent circular `#include` statements.

Comment: Include guards effectively prevent circular inclusions by simply ignoring the second inclusion. If code after that depends on the included headers though, you get the errors you have. Solution: Declare the types. BTW: _GOOD and _USER are not macros that you are allowed to use, since they are reserved. With these very generic names, you are also running a real chance of creating a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular reference. In short, you end up with something like this:

```
class Good
{
    User * fn() {} // What is a User?
};

class User
{
    Good * fn() {}
};
```

C++ doesn't behave like C# and reads files top-down, so when it encounters the first reference to User, it yet doesn't know, what it is. Even if you switch the sequence of classes, the problem will return.

You probably should put them in the same file and use type forwarding:

```
class User;

class Good
{
    User * fn() {} // Ah, User is some class. Go on.
};

class User
{
    Good * fn() {}
};
```

Or (as Agentlien suggests):

```
class User;

class Good
{
    User fn();
};

class User
{
    Good fn();
};

User Good::fn() { return User(); }

Good User::fn() { return Good(); }
```

Comment: This won't compile, either, since you're defining the function `Good::fn` inside the class definition. Doing this, the return type cannot be an incomplete type, so forward-declaring it doesn't solve the problem. You would also need to move the function definition to after the definition of `User`.

Comment: @Agentlien You're right, I thought of `User *` and `Good *`, but written `User` and `Good` instead. Thanks for verification. Modified the codes, they will both compile now.

Comment: That's a lot better. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, the first time the compiler reaches the definition of a class or function all types it uses need to be declared. So, for instance, having:

```
void importGood(Good &g);
```

in *User.h*, means `Good` has to be declared before this function declaration. This is best done using a **forward-declaration**, which is simply written as a line such as:

```
class Good;
```

This needs to be put before the declaration of any function which uses this type, since otherwise the compiler doesn't know that it is the name of a type, and you get compiler errors.

Normally, it would also work to simply `#include` the file where this type is defined. However, this method has two drawbacks:

1. It is a lot more expensive. Even if you use include guards, the system still has to read and tokenize the file before it can determine that you're not interested in its contents.
2. Whenever you have a circular dependency such as in your case, it won't help. The compiler will simply start compiling, for example, *User.cpp*. It'll then include *User.h*, and will almost immediately come across the `#include "Good.h"`. From then on, it'll enter *Good.h*. There, you're (again) trying to `#include User.h`, which will be largely ignored due to the include guard. So, as soon as it comes upon any use of `User` in *Good.h*, the compiler still hasn't seen its declaration.

The forward-declaration solves this, by putting the declaration of a class directly inside the file where it's used, before its first use.

In general, you should prefer to use forward declarations in header files, and avoid including other headers. whenever possible.

The only time you actually need to include something directly from a header is when you're creating an instance of a type declared in that header (for example, by having it as a member variable which is not a pointer or reference) or when you're using members (such as functions or member variables) of that class in the header. This is one reason why it's always a good idea to put function definitions inside the cpp files, rather than the headers.